# How to draw a line with a custom style using Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm currently drawing a line using Core Graphics. It's really bare bones and simple.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 300.0f, 600.0f);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 25);
    CGContextSetLineCap(c, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

This works well. Let's say that we wanted to draw a custom style line. Say we wanted to imitate the style of a crayon for example. And that the designer handed your crayon style images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcazJ.jpg

To do accomplish this effect I think I need to do something like this:

1. Create a special colored versions of crayonImage1-crayonImage4
2. Every time you add a line to line you use one of the crayonImages
3. You alternate the crayonImages every time you draw a point.

Step 1 makes sense. I can use the following method:

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage *)img withColor:(UIColor *)color {    
    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}
```

I'm unsure how I can complete steps 2 and 3. Is there an API in CoreGraphics for setting an image as the point of line? If so what is it and how can I use it?

Thanks in advance,

-David

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following example: http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

But for brushes, don't draw a line. Simply draw the brush image using CGContextDrawImage.

Basically, you simply draw an image for every touch.

Comment: Doesn't drawing the brush image every time become very very slow?

Comment: You don't draw the ENTIRE history every time. Check the code: after you draw something, you replace the content of the image with the new image (containing the new brush). The next draw will occur on top of the previous one. As long as you don't care for history (undo/redo), you don't need to worry about performances.

Keep in mind - QuartzCore is designed to work with bitmaps and it is highly optimized to handle them properly. Drawing an image is like a walk in the park :)